# Copy text to other input field onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to copy the value of one input field to another on blur. Here's my code:

```
$( "input[id$=token-input-search_field]" ).blur( function() {
    $(this).val() = $('input[id$=search_field]').val;
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing the parantheses. val() is a function.

Answer (score 4):

```
$( "input[id$=token-input-search_field]" ).blur( function() {
    $(this).val( $('input[id$=search_field]').val() );
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but it doesn't make much sense to change the value of the "blurred" element.

Comment: Ok, yes, this is what I want to do; but it doesn't copy the text as expected, even though console log shows nothing. I have a dependency called jQuery tokeninput which changes the value to "" onblur. However, I cannot edit the dependency file to change this. Is there a way to override this?

Comment: You have to store the value you want before the tokeninput kicks in and then re-apply it - http://jsfiddle.net/vKb6N/

Comment: ok, that does something, but the field now displays [object] [Object] onblur.

Comment: probably you have several inputs that match `$('input[id$=search_field]')` so jQuery pastes in the whole object of matched values. Select from that object the value you need

Comment: Nope, I only have one `#search_field` input

Comment: `input[id$=search_field]` and `#search_field` are ***very*** different. The first grabs ALL input fields with the ID that ends in `search_field`. Even in your 2 lines of code you provided here both `token-input-search_field` and `search_field` will match that selector. So you do have several entries in your object. To fix that use `#search_field` instead of `input[id$=search_field]`